# Python Deque - 10 minutes worth of data

Tags: python, performance, time, deque

I'm trying to write a script that, when executed, appends a new available piece of information and removes data that's over 10 minutes old.

I'm wondering whats the the most efficient way, performance wise, of keeping track of the specific time to each information element while also removing the data over 10 minutes old.

My novice thought would be to append the information with a time stamp - [info, time] - to the deque and in a while loop continuously evaluate the end of the deque to remove anything older than 10 minutes... I doubt this is the best way.

Can someone provide an example?  Thanks.

Comment: The algorithm you describe is how I'd do it. I can't think of any big ways to improve on it.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to use a sorted tree structure, keyed on the timestamps. Then you can find the first element >= 10 minutes ago, and remove everything before that.

Using the [`bintrees`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/) library as an example (because its key-slicing syntax makes this very easy to read and write…):

```
q = bintrees.FastRBTree.Tree()
now = datetime.datetime.now()
q[now] = 'a'
q[now - datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)] = 'b'
q[now - datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)] = 'c'
q[now - datetime.timedelta(seconds=15)] = 'd'

now = datetime.datetime.now()
del q[:now - datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)]
```

That will remove everything up to, but not including, now-10s, which should be both `c` and `d`.

This way, finding the first element to remove takes log N time, and removing N elements below that should be average case amortized log N but worst case N. So, your overall worst case time complexity doesn't improve, but your average case does.

Of course the overhead of managing a tree instead of a deque is pretty high, and could easily be higher than the savings of N/log N steps if you're dealing with a pretty small queue.

---

There are other logarithmic data structures that map be more appropriate, like a pqueue/heapqueue (as implemented by `heapq` in the stdlib), or a clock ring; I just chose a red-black tree because (with a PyPI module) it was the easiest one to demonstrate.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the detailed explanation.  The queue will be variable but will be large on average.

Comment: By "large" do you mean "hundreds" or "millions"? Although really, a better solution than trying to figure that out would be to test it with you real data using `timeit`.

Comment: High thousands to millions.  Do you believe that gives using a deque the upper hand?  If not, I'm definitely going to utilize timeit here - I'm in no hurry.

Comment: @Rook: That's just about the range where it's least worth guessing. :) Meanwhile, take a look at my other answer and see if the added restrictions there are applicable to your use case. If so, there may be an even better solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only ever appending to the end, and the values are always inherently in sorted order, you don't actually need a logarithmic data structure like a tree or heap at all; you can do a logarithmic search within any sorted random-access structure like a `list` or `collections.deque`.

The problem is that deleting everything up to an arbitrary point in a `list` or `deque` takes O(N) time. There's no reason that it *should*; you should be able to drop N elements off a deque in amortized constant time (with `del q[:pos]` or `q.popleft(pos)`), it's just that `collections.deque` doesn't do that. If you find or write a deque class that *does* have that feature, you could just write this:

```
q = deque()
now = datetime.datetime.now()
q.append((now, 'a'))
q.append((now - datetime.timedelta(seconds=5), 'b')
q.append((now - datetime.timedelta(seconds=10), 'c')
q.append((now - datetime.timedelta(seconds=15), 'd')

now = datetime.datetime.now()
pos = bisect.bisect_left(q, now - datetime.timedelta(seconds=10))
del q[:pos]
```

I'm not sure whether a `deque` like this exists on PyPI, but [the C source to collections.deque](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#l4) is available to fork, or the [Python source from PyPy](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/2d71669b2c3c383710be2ed5a5179abde097b27d/lib_pypy/_collections.py?at=default#cl-23), or you could wrap a C or C++ `deque` type, or write one from scratch…

---

Or, if you're expecting that the "current" values in the deque will always be a small subset of the total length, you can do it in O(M) time just by not using the deque destructively:

```
q = q[pos:]
```

In fact, in that case, you might as well just use a `list`; it has O(1) append on the right, and slicing the last M items off a list is about as low-overhead a way to copy M items as you're going to find.

Comment: Actually, the values are always inherently in sorted order.  I just never thought of using a list because it was my understanding a deque's primary purpose was to be more efficient in removing data - ignorance.  However, the "current" values will always be a larger subset of the total length.  Probably 10x so.

Comment: @Rook: Yes, deque's primary purpose is to be more efficient in removing data from the left. The reason the postscript suggested using a `list` is that if you do things that way, you're not removing data from the left anymore. But if your current data will be large, that postscript can be ignored.

Comment: @Rook: For the main answer, you _are_ removing from the left. And, while removing N elements from the start of a list is about as low-overhead an O(N) operation can get, it's still O(N); for a deque, in theory, it's O(B) where B is the number of blocks used by those N elements, which should be amortized constant time, it's just that you have to write the code for that; otherwise, you have to call `popleft` N  times, which is O(N), and a slower O(N) than list slicing…

Comment: Unfortunately it will be.  However, dropping N elements by del q[:pos] intrigues me alot more than while looping the end of the deque.  I think I'll be trying to go that route, given I haven't had experience with buckets. :)

Comment: How much slower is o(n) than list slicing?  I know o(n) always depends on the size but say if i'm dealing with 1 million elements.  Am I being drastically more efficient with list slicing than just calling popleft a million times?

Comment: @Rook: Let's say you have 2M elements, and you want to keep 1M. In that case, calling `popleft` 1M times will probably be about 100x slower (at least with CPython) than just copying the right 1M. On the other hand, if you have 200M elements and want to keep 199M, copying the right 199M will be a little slower, and will also create memory pressure that might slow things down a lot more. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Rook: Anyway, the problem with `del q[:pos]` is that `collections.deque` doesn't deal with slices. Also, looking at the source, it's apparently implemented as a linked list of small fixed-size blocks, so you couldn't actually write an O(1) implementation, just a linear one that's faster by a factor of the block size, which  is around 60 (and it could also do the looping in C, of course).

Comment: It makes perfect sense.  Thanks so much for your time.  For now I'll use popleft - but I think for fun I'll try to find or attempt to develop the del[:pos] algorithm you suggested for experience. :)

Comment: @Rook: You should really take another look at the bucket idea. If it's OK for elements to stick around a little longer than they're supposed to (until the next minute), it's very easy and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another answer, with even more constraints:

If you can bucket things with, e.g., one-minute precision, all you need is 10 lists.

Unlike my other constrained answer, this doesn't require that you only ever append on the right; you can append in the middle (although you'll come after any other values for the same minute).

The down side is that you can't actually remove everything more than 10 minutes old; you can only remove everything in the 10th bucket, which could be off by up to 1 minute. You can choose what this means by choosing how to round:

- Truncate one way, and nothing ever gets dropped too early, but everything is dropped late, an average of 30 seconds and at worst 60.
- Truncate the other way, and nothing ever gets dropped late, but everything is dropped early, an average of 30 seconds and at worst 60.
- Round at half, and things get dropped both early and late, but with an average of 0 seconds and a worst case of 30.

And you can of course use smaller buckets, like 100 buckets of 6-second intervals instead of 10 buckets of 1-minute intervals, to cut the error down as far as you like. Push that *too* far and you'll ruin the efficiency; a list of 600000 buckets of 1ms intervals is nearly as slow as a list of 1M entries.* But if you need 1 second or even 50ms, that's probably fine.

Here's a simple example:

```
def prune_queue(self):
    now = time.time() // 60
    age = now - self.last_bucket_time
    if age:
        self.buckets = self.buckets[-(10-age):] + [[] for _ in range(age)]
        self.last_bucket_time = now

def enqueue(self, thing):
    self.prune_queue()
    self.buckets[-1].append(thing)
```

---

* Of course you could combine this with the logarithmic data structure—a red-black tree of 600000 buckets is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a class for this based on Deque, a FIFO queue.

```py
import collections
from dataclasses import dataclass
import typing
import time
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@dataclass
class DequeItem:
    time: float
    value: typing.Any


class TimeDeque:
    """
    A timedeque is a deque which will keep records for the specified number of seconds.
    """

    def __init__(
        self, time_window_seconds: int = 600, get_time_fn: typing.Callable = time.time
    ):
        self.time_window_seconds = time_window_seconds
        self.get_time_fn = get_time_fn
        self._deque = collections.deque()

    def prune(self) -> bool:
        """
        Remove any items from the left of the deque which are older than
        `self.time_window_seconds`. Can probably be called less and save
        some time if we delegate use of this to the programmer.
        """

        try:
            while self.get_time_fn() - self._deque[-1].time > self.time_window_seconds:
                self._deque.popleft()
        except IndexError as e:
            """
            If self._deque[-1] fails, the deque is empty
            """
            return True

        log.debug("Pruned %d items from deque", len(self._deque))
        return True

    def append(self, item) -> bool:
        time = self.get_time_fn()
        self._deque.append(DequeItem(time, item))
        assert self.prune()
        return True

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        self.prune()
        return len(self._deque)

    def __iter__(self):
        self.prune()
        for ob in self._deque:
            yield ob.value
```

You can use it like this:

```py
# create a timedeque for 10 minutes worth of data
td = timedeque.TimeDeque(600)

# append data to your queue
td.append(1)
td.append(2)
td.append(3)

# perform some operation on the deque

agg = sum(td)
# agg = 6
```

Comment: Very nice, if I understand correctly though, we should check the time for the left-most value in the deque, rather than the right most `while self.get_time_fn() - self._deque[-1].time > self.time_window_seconds:` should be`while self.get_time_fn() - self._deque[0].time > self.time_window_seconds:`